# TypeScript ReactDOM Property 'type' is missing on component

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, typescript

Getting the following error:

```
Error   TS2345  Argument of type 'typeof SomeComponent' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<{}>'.
Property 'type' is missing in type 'typeof SomeComponent'.
```

Got the following code typescript code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

interface IProps{}    
interface IState {}

class SomeComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
}

var component = SomeComponent;
var root = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(component , root);
```

I tried the following:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    render() {
        return <div />;
    }

    get type() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
interface IProps{}    
interface IState {}

class SomeComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent /> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

You don't pass the component class to the `render` function, you need to pass the instance.

---

### Edit

This:

```
var component = SomeComponent;
```

Assigns a reference to the class `SomeComponent` into the `component` variable, meaning that if you do that then you can do both and they are the same:

```
var componentInstance1 = <SomeComponent />
var componentInstance2 = <component />
```

If you don't want to use the jsx/tsx notation then when constructing the component you need to pass the props:

```
var component = new SomeComponent(props);
```

Comment: Doesn't this make it an `instance`? `var component = SomeComponent;`

Comment: Will ask another question why.

Comment: No. `SomeComponent` is a class not an instance of that class. Usually you'll get an instance with the `new` keyword (`new SomeComponent()`) but you use jsx so `<SomeComponent />` does that work for you

Comment: lol. Ok I get it, so var x = SomeComponent, sets the `typeof(SomeComponent)`  to var x. so was missing `
var component = new SomeComponent();` Thanks!

Comment: Will mark it as answer in 4 min once i can (time limit)

Comment: No, you're wrong with your assumptions, I revised my answer to explain, also you editing my answer wasn't appropriate and wasn't correct either.

Comment: you don't have to pass in props as it has a default ctor

Comment: You don't have to if your component doesn't rely on them.  But just wanted to make it clear that this is how it's done in case you do.  Most examples show the jsx way of doing things.